# Implementing data validation with error messages

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm currently developing a linear optimization tool and I want to guarantee the validity of my input data. Therefore, I've defined various "validate" methods, e.g.:

```
validates :production_coefficient_machines, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}, :allow_nil => true
```

I really want to include descriptive error messages. I have tried:

```
validates :storage_cost, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0, :message => "Please enter positive values"}, :allow_nil => true
```

The validation works, but I won't see any error messages. I also tried adding the method to the form.html:

```
<%= form_for(@product_a) do |f| %>
        <% if @product_a.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@product_a.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product_a from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
                <% @product_a.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

to the index.html, but since the method is written for the product_a form, it won't work in the index.html.

How can I easily implement error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Controller` should not direct you to your `index` action if your product has not been saved, it should re-render your `new` action which would have the above form. Inside the form you can display your errors using the

```
f.error_messages
```

method of the form builder.